# Is a dead diode actually a shorting?

Tags: diodes

I had a little project running with an arduino pro mini. had external psu connected and connected my programmer with power onto it. smoke came up. hole in the diode. now my question:

Is a dead diode actually a short in the circuit? So that i have to desolder it?

Comment: You can see it as a resistor with random value...

Comment: Hole in diode: diodes should not have holes. Yes replace it ! You could just remove (and not place a new one) but then you would have no protection if you reverse-power the board again. Diodes are much cheaper than Arduino boards so just place new one.

Comment: Diodes certainly can fail as dead shorts. Measure it with a DMM (both ways round).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure mode of a component is not predictable. It can fail both open or short. Measure it to be sure but replacing it is always the best course of action.